# Xcode says some of my pods are not PIEs, is this fine?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, cocoapods

Today, after I uploaded an archive to the app store, Xcode shows me this warning and a few others (all are similar).

Here is one of them:

> WARNING ITMS-90080: "The executable 'Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/EZLoadingActivity.framework' is not a Position Independent Executable. Please ensure that your build settings are configured to create PIE executables. For more information refer to Technical Q&A QA1788 - Building a Position Independent Executable in the iOS Developer Library."
>   WARNING ITMS-90080: "The executable 'Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/EZLoadingActivity.framework' is not a Position Independent Executable. Please ensure that your build settings are configured to create PIE executables. For more information refer to Technical Q&A QA1788 - Building a Position Independent Executable in the iOS Developer Library."

So apparently this stuff is pretty important that it needs to be said twice.

`EZLoadingActivity` is a cocoapod that I'm using to write my app. Since it is a library, it cannot be run on its own. Therefore, I think it's ok for it to not be a Position Independent Executable. But when the warning showed up, I think something must have gone wrong.

I have seen another question whose OP's binary got rejected because of this error. So I'm afraid that my binary will also be rejected.

Will my binary be rejected? Is it fine to have frameworks that are not PIEs? I have other apps that use cocoapods but they don't have this warning when I upload them. This is the first time that I encountered such a warning? Is this serious? What can I do?

Comment: wish i had a pie right about now

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's a temporary iTunesConnect issue.

I've inspected older archives that passed without warning.
Then, I found that all the embedded frameworks built don't have the PIE flag regardless of what build setting was used.

So, a missing PIE flag for frameworks should not be a reason for a warning.

I think that Apple changed the server side validation and introduced some bugs.

Comment: Bugs in PIEs ? Eek :x

Comment: Frameworks [can not have the PIE flag](https://github.com/aosm/ld64/blob/88428de93dab43bf5fc5baca9ee38226bc013269/src/ld/Options.cpp#L3437-L3440) since it’s for main executables only. So that’s definitely a bug on the validation side.

Comment: Xcode spits out this warning for all my pods as well. But then iTunes Connect processes it and allows it for release. Is releasing updates with this warning going to cause problems?

Comment: Is there any official or new information regarding the issue?

Comment: For me, iTunes Connect doesn't complain about PIEs anymore now.